# Safari downloading MP4s multiple times

Tags: video, safari, mp4

I have a pretty simple HTML page that has 11 videos on it.
I use a basic video tag and this seems to work just fine on all browsers besides Safari.
It looks like it's loading every MP4 twice and in one case, three times, more than doubling the amount a user needs to download.
Here's the code used and I've also attached a screenshot of the network overview:

```
<video class="video" id="video01" muted>
    <source src="mp4/architecturalart01.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

[image]